# DHCPREQUEST: send_packet: Operation not permitted

Tags: configuration, network-configuration, error, whonix, firewall

seeing a lot of this in my whonix gateway logs. Should I be concerned or do anything about it?

```
    $ journalctl -af

Jun 02 19:41:30 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:41:30 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:41:30 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:41:34 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:41:34 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:41:34 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:41:45 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:41:45 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:41:45 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:42:00 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:42:00 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:42:00 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:42:20 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:42:20 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:42:20 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:42:35 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:42:35 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:42:35 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:42:51 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:42:51 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:42:51 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:43:06 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:43:06 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:43:06 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:43:22 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:43:22 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:43:22 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:43:38 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:43:38 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:43:38 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:43:50 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:43:50 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:43:50 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
    Jun 02 19:44:01 host dhclient[884]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.122.1 port 67
    Jun 02 19:44:01 host dhclient[884]: send_packet: Operation not permitted
    Jun 02 19:44:01 host dhclient[884]: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.


    user@host:~$ lsb_release -a

    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Whonix
    Description:    Whonix GNU/Linux 8.8 (jessie)
    Release:        8.8
    Codename:       jessie

    user@host:~$ uname -a

    Linux host 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30) i686 GNU/Linux

    root@host:/home/user# apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -V

    Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease                                                       
    Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie InRelease                                               
    Hit http://deb.whonix.org jessie InRelease     
    Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main i386 Packages        
    Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg                                     
    Hit http://deb.whonix.org jessie/main i386 Packages                   
    Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib i386 Packages                     
    Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free i386 Packages                                          
    Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release                                                                   
    Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en                                          
    Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main i386 Packages                                                        
    Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en                                             
    Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/contrib i386 Packages                                                     
    Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en                                         
    Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/non-free i386 Packages                                                    
    Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en                                                    
    Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en                                                       
    Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en                                                   
    Ign http://deb.whonix.org jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                       
    Ign http://deb.whonix.org jessie/main Translation-en                                                          
    Reading package lists... Done                                                                                 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Whonix doesn't provide or use DHCP as far as I know. What have you changed in your network configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow Whonix documentation for combining VPNs. Otherwise they conflict with Whonix's firewall.

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnels/Introduction

> Should I be concerned or do anything about it?

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/FAQ#Am_I_compromised.3F